# Code to know what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have this simple snippet, well not too simple that I needed to know how to make the connection or maybe a tip to tell me what code is this? appreciated. From the tags I'm assuming its one of them:

```
function Container(connectionString) {
  var dataFetched = true;
  var dbConnection = DbConnection(connectionString);
}

Container.prototype.getData = function () {
  if (!this.dataFetched)
    throw "Data not fetched!";

  return this.data;
}

Container.prototype.fetch = function () {
  this.dbConnection.getAllData(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      delete this.data;
      this.dataFetched = false;
      return false;
        } else {
          this.data = result;
          this.dataFetched = true;
          return true;
        }
      });
    }

function DbConnection(connectionString) { }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. This should be closed by offtopic or unclear what you're asking

Comment: i just want to know which of the tags is this code from? coz i haven't seen this `*.prototype.*` stuff before

Comment: @rockStar prototypal inheritance!

Comment: Good old javascript.

Comment: @rockStar See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) question for more information on prototype.

Comment: thank you, now i know..thats what im looking for :) @marie and paul

Comment: You are spent a lot of time asking what the hell is `prototype` while if you google 20 seconds you'll obtain the answer. Stackoverflow is a site for specific problems that helps another users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's JavaScript code.

The `.prototype` property in JavaScript is a major feature of JavaScript's prototypal inheritance.

Googling "JavaScript prototypal inheritance" will yield a huge number of resources. Just grabbing one from the first page, this looks like a reasonably concise summary: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/javascript-prototypical-inheritance-explained.html#fbid=ouJBLxsSAyT

Comment: thank you, a link would be gud where to start studying this :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain